# How to add react component inside .Net aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, reactjs

I have one react app which provides multiple components like `<Button> <Label>`. I want to render those component inside apsx page. 
For example.

```
<div>
<ReactComponent/>
</div>
```

I know we can use iframe in aspx page to render react app or @script.render in cshmtl file. But am looking for some another way to render inside aspx page.
am new to dot net. I have created one ASP.Net web Application using MS visual studio.Any help would be really helpful..

Got this github link for this. [enter link description here](https://github.com/xabikos/ReactjsWebForms) 
Now I want to understand how I can add multiple react components, webpack, babel, package.json etc.

Comment: You cannot directly use React components inside of the ASP.net web pages.

Check React Portals
https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a  with a class (e.g. "react-component") and then in your JS code do the following: 
ReactDOM.render(, document.querySelector('react-component'));

Comment: hey, got this https://github.com/xabikos/ReactjsWebForms , do you know how i can add multiple components, webpack, babel to it. Or is there a way to use bundle.js